# Jira channel statuses in Leverice

Tags: jira, integration, message, channel

Can I edit which icons relate to which Jira items depending on their statuses, or is this set by default once the Jira integration is set up in Leverice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set this up by using the /bindStatus command.

In the message box in your Jira channel in Leverice, type in the following command:

**/showAvailableStatuses** — this will provide a list of the Leverice statuses (**Open, Assigned, InProgress, Done, Reopened**)

Your own Jira statuses will likely be different from the above 5 Leverice statuses, so you need pick which of your Jira statuses to tie to which Leverice statuses (can tie multiple Jira statuses to a single Leverice status). This will ensure that the different event icons in your Leverice Jira integration work properly.

The syntax is as follows to tie your own Jira statuses to Leverice icon statuses [note the single quotation marks], and here are a couple examples:

**/bindStatus Open “issue.status.name == ‘Your Company Jira Term For Open Item’”**

**/bindStatus Assigned “issue.status.name == ‘Your Company Jira Term For Assigned Item’”**

etc.

Similarly, you can untie a Leverice status from a Jira status using the following syntax:

**/unbindStatus Open “issue.status.name == ‘Your Company Jira Term For Open Item’”**

To view a list of which status bindings you have created, use the command **/showBoundStatuses**

Next you can also set up automatic archiving and unarchiving of Jira channels if you want. For example, if you want the Jira item channel in Leverice to archive automatically when its Jira status is changed to Done, you use the following command:

**/bindCommand /archive “issue.status.name == ‘Done’”**

To unarchive automatically when status is changed from Done to something else:

**/bindCommand /unarchive “issue.status.name != ‘Done’”**

To untie an automatic command from a status then use the following syntax:

**/unbindCommand /archive “issue.status.name == ‘Done’”**

To view a list of which automatic commands you have created, use the command **/showBoundCommands**